# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) after trying to install wine

Tags: 16.04, apt, permissions, wine

I just tried to install Internet Explorer using [these instructions on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingInternetExplorer).  It brought up a terms of service screen in the terminal, which I couldn't figure out how to accept, so I ended up closing the terminal.  I'm now getting this error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Looking at this question, [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process), I tried Faheem's answer, but got this error.

```
kill -9 3849
bash: kill: (3849) - Operation not permitted
```

What else can I do?  It looked like the other answers could really mess up the system, and as I am new to Linux, I don't want to risk anything to mess it up too badly.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: delete the lock files, as said in the answer to the question you have mentioned.

Comment: Do you delete the files with kill -9?  Or do I have to go manually do it?  If so , where do I find them?

Comment: you need `sudo kill -9 3849`. don't delete the lock files. rebooting will also release the files

Comment: I just deleted the locked files a few seconds before this answer.  Is there anything I should do to get them back?  I also tried rebooting before I asked this question

Answer (score 1):

Everytime I encounter this error is because I have Synaptic Package Manager on and haven't noticed it. Just quit Synaptic and you ll be good to go.